# Rectangular co ordinates between two points in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

How to get the rectangular coordinates between two points in JavaScript as an object? For example `foo(10, 20, 30, 40)` should return `(10, 40)` and `(30, 20)`

Comment: `function(a,b,c,d){return [[a,d],[c,b]]}`?

Comment: And, if not that, what are you doing? I can't quite see how your example relates to points and coordinates.

Comment: You should definitely use jQuery for this.

Comment: @Crescent - [Definitely, 100% agree :)](http://img180.imageshack.us/img180/3305/addanumbertoanothernumb.png)

Comment: My intention was how to get the answer in object form

Comment: Wait, what are your two points?  `(10,20)` and `(30,40)`?

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript "everything" is an Object.  This means strings, numbers, arrays, functions.

JavaScript has built-in objects such as String, Date, Array, and more.

An object is just a special kind of data, with properties and methods.

You can create a new instance of an object multiple a few ways:

```
var foo = new Object();
foo.bar = 'baz';
```

Or using an object literal:

```
var foo = {bar: 'baz'};
```

Or using an object constructor:

```
function foo(arg){
    this.bar = arg;
}

var aFoo = new foo('baz');
```